# Redis pubsub and twitter like newsfeed?

Tags: twitter, redis, publish-subscribe, feed

I checked out Redis pub/sub functionality and at first glance it looks perfect for something like forming a twitter feed.
However I tried to google for Redis pub/sub and newsfeed and I can barely find any example or use case about this. If Redis is actually not good for this, what are the disadvantages?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Redis pub/sub is not a data storage, but just a data flow channel.

For example(**Chronologically sequenced**)

1. You create a channel named `news:feed`
2. User A joins `news:feed`
3. User B publishes to `news:feed`

This scenario works fine. But the following doesn't:

1. You create a channel named `news:feed`
2. User B publishes to `news:feed`
3. User A joins `news:feed`

In this case, user A will never receive the message published by User B, before he (A) joined.

If you want to implement newsfeed using pub/sub, you have to create several channels (at least as many as users). Here is an implementation of a simple Twitter clone: http://redis.io/topics/twitter-clone